# how to implement 3 nested subquery with 3 model in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I have 3 model `Transaction` , `Cart` , `Acceptedcart`.

in `Cart` model I have `transaction_id` and in `Acceptedcart` model have `cart_id`.

how can I find `transactions` where `acceptedcart->delivered == true` ?

can I write that like this ?

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereIn('id',function ($query) {
        return Cart::whereIn('id' , function($subquery){
            return AcceptedCart::where('delivered' , false)->pluck('cart_id');
        })->pluck('transaction_id');
    })->get();
```

or :

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereIn('id' , function($query){
        $query->select('transaction_id')->from('carts')->whereIn('id' , function($subquery){
            $subquery->select('cart_id')->from('accepted_carts')->where('delivered' , true);
        });
    })->get();
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Transaction.php your relationship to carts:

```
public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
}
```

in Cart.php you relationship to accepted carts:

```
public function accepted_carts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Acceptedcart::class);
}
```

And the query to get the transactions where `acceptedcart->delivered == true`:

```
$transactions = Transaction::whereHas('carts.accepted_carts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('delivered', true);
})->get();
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'true' in 'where clause'

Comment: change to `$query->where('delivered', true);`, I've updated the answer

Comment: How can I get `->sum('accepted_count')` in the `accepted_carts` model ?

Comment: `Acceptedcart::sum('accepted_count')` will get you the sum of the column in this model